# Why does importing copies of the database dump and the document root make WordPress data inconsistent?

Tags: database, migration, backup

I'm experiencing the following problem: I have a local copy of my WordPress site and a corresponding live version on my server.

I added some new blog categories on my local version and created some new blog posts.

Then, I made a database dump and a copy of the document root files from the local version. After I did that, I made a backup of the old document root files on my server and deleted them. Afterwards I've copied the local copies of the database dump and php files on my server, inserted the database dump, placed the local PHP files on the servers document root and checked if everything is alright with `wp-config.php`.

And now guess what? The posts and categories structures where totally messed up. Old posts had the new categories assign (ones, which were created on the local system) and the new posts were only drafts and had no content and no categories assigned.

What my expectation was: As I have removed all "old" server files (database files and document root) and inserted both a fresh database copy and a fresh document root copy, I expected that everything will look like my local copy of WordPress. Also a few month ago I experienced the same problem when I changed some stuff in my navigation menu locally and updated the files on the server (including the database) with fresh copies from the local system - the menu on the server was then messed up.

This means to me that WordPress somehow remembers some old state, which is totally weird to me as I can not image how it is doing that as both database and PHP files are **exactly** the same as on my local system.

Does anyone has an idea of what is happening here?

Comment: Are you doing a search and replace for urls in the database during this process?

Comment: No. I was just updating `home` and `siteurl` from the `wp_options` table. I thought, that this is sufficient. Should I replace all database URLs from local to live in the database? Is this my mistake?

Comment: I recommend doing that as long as you're not replacing the guid. I would also make sure you're emptying the database before importing your new content. It sounds like some post ids were mixed up which might be due to auto increment settings.

Comment: I did empty the database, but it did not help. What do you mean by `guid`? Also it's strange how something can be incremented if you mirror the files on another server and this server is using exactly the same data as local - still very strange to me.

Comment: The posts table contains a guid that basically should never change. It sounds to me like the ids are getting mixed up, so I would check to make sure something isn't going wrong with the auto increment settings in the database, ie are they starting from 0 before import.